# Expo Notifications: Stopped being able to receive notifications on iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am implementing `expo-notifications` into my react native app. Notifications have been working fine up until a couple weeks ago and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Everything on Android is working properly, but on iOS I'm not able to receive notifications. I've checked and I have notifications allowed in my settings and am receiving a "valid" ExpoPushToken because I was able to put that push token into their [testing tool](https://expo.dev/notifications) without error. I also tested it myself on postman using their [api](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/) and received a status of "ok", but still didn't see a notification on my phone.

Here's my code for getting the token:

```
    async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
        let token;
        if (Device.isDevice) {
            const { status: existingStatus } =
                await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
            let finalStatus = existingStatus;
            if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
                const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync({
                    ios: {
                        allowAlert: true,
                        allowBadge: true,
                        allowSound: true,
                    },
                });
                finalStatus = status;
            }
            if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
                // alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
                return;
            }
            token = (
                await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
                    experienceId: "@username/app-slug",
                })
            ).data;
            console.log(token);
        }

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
                name: "default",
                importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
                vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
                lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
            });
        }

        return token;
    }
```

Obviously `@username` and `app-slug` are my username and slug for my expo project.

The only thing that I know has changed is I've upgraded to Expo SDK 46 and I added in the `experienceId` into the `getExpoPushTokenAsync` function. Could adding `experienceId` screw up receiving notifications? Or is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I had multiple Push Keys that were set up in my Apple Developer account. I revoked both and had expo generate a new one using `eas credentials` and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked for me too. Was spending ages trying to work this out.